# split one row into two or add two entities in single row

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I would like to represent data in the datagridview like mentioned below. I have google it for the answer but no success. I have sucessfully added colums (Student Name) but not rows i.e. Subject and marks. I tried with Datatable concept and cell wise copy but no result.

[image]

```
            int Selectedindex = comboBox3.SelectedIndex;
            Equipment slectedEq = m_equipmentList.ElementAt(Selectedindex); // I am explaining data structure (original data is different) as a students data which is stored in "m_equipmentList"
            string P_chname;       
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();

            for (int i = 0; i < slectedEq.m_ChannelAccess.Count; i++)
            {
                ChannelAccess chAccess = m_equipmentList.ElementAt(Selectedindex).m_ChannelAccess.ElementAt(i);
                P_chname = slectedEq.m_ChannelAccess.ElementAt(i).m_deviceName;// example:  here I get student Name
                Dt.Columns.Add(P_chname);
                for (int j = 0; j < slectedEq.m_ChannelAccess.ElementAt(i).m_Parameters.Count; j++)
                {
                    string prName;
                    string prValue;
                    prName= chAccess.m_Parameters.ElementAt(j).m_paramName; // Here i get subject name 
                    prValue = chAccess.m_Parameters.ElementAt(j).m_ParamValue;// Here i get subject marks
                    object[] RowValues = { "", "" };

                    //assign values into row object
                    RowValues[0] = prName;
                    RowValues[1] = prValue;

                    //create new data row
                    DataRow dRow;
                    dRow = Dt.Rows.Add(RowValues);
                    Dt.AcceptChanges();



                }

                dataGridView1.DataSource = Dt;
            }
```

The above one is an example picture how I would like add a dataviewgrid. Can some one has idea how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code which you tried already?

Comment: I think the question might be easier to understand if you stick to one nomenclature, i.e. either use 'students and subjects' or 'equipment/ChannelAccess and parameters'...

Comment: Yes your right, Added just to show concept clearly

Answer (score 1):

As I think this is hard to do with a `DataGridView`, I suggest using two nested `ItemsControl`s:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding to some IEnumerable<Student>, Mode=OneWay}">
    <!-- template for each student -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Student}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <!-- template for each subject -->
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Subject}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mark}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- template for the inner control -->
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <!-- template for the outer control -->
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

assuming you have students defined similar to this:

```
class Student
{
    string Name{ get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Subject>{ get; set; }
}
```

and subjects similar to this:

```
class Subject
{
    string Name{ get; set; }
    int Mark{ get;set; }
}
```

You may want to add some `Borders` and define some `Width`s to make it look nice. Also, if you want to edit names and marks, you may want to replace the `TextBlock`s by `TextBox`es.